# How to remove highlight of combobox when an Item is selected in Vb?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, highlight

In load page event:

I read some data from DB and then add this data to Combo box then select an item as default and enable of combo box changes to false.
When I load this page, the item witch selected highlights with blue color.

How to remove this highlight?

Comment: no. Vb.net. I write ComboBox1.selectionLenth=0 in selectIndexChanged but it's not work

Comment: VB.NET may be used in different types of projects: ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, etc. ASP.NET is a website language with VB.NET or C# as back-end code. -- So this is Windows Forms then? (I asked about ASP.NET because I reacted to you saying _"load **page** event"_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify its [**`SelectionLength` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionlength(v=vs.110).aspx), which gets or sets how many characters have been selected (highlighted).

Just set it to `0` after you have selected the default item and you should be good to go:

```
ComboBox1.SelectionLength = 0
```

---

**EDIT:**

In your case this code is executed before the `Load` event has finished. Due to this the form has not been rendered yet, which is why it is not working for you.

The simple fix is to add this in the form's `Shown` event too:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    ComboBox1.SelectionLength = 0
End Sub
```

If you don't want the caret to be in the beginning you can also add this line to set it to the end of the text:

```
ComboBox1.SelectionStart = ComboBox1.Text.Length
```

Comment: @user3560351 : Please define "not work", because that doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: I dont know what is problem :(   i tried every way to sole it. but i cann't

Comment: same here, Visual Studio 2016, vb net.. it ignores selectionstart or selectionlength and hilight the selected element.

Comment: @Zibri : Could you explain your downvote? This works in WinForms, but the OP didn't state if it was ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution does not work in VB.NET 2016
The easiest way to do is to pass focus to another element like a label in the SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Are you using WinForms or ASP.NET for this? The VB.NET version usually doesn't matter, the .NET version might however.